# No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, maven-3

I run

```
mvn jetty:run
```

command and I am getting

> --No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from
>    the repositories [local (C:\work.m2\repository), error--

**controller**

```
package com.himtech.googlechart;
//imports are here

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/gcharts")
public class GglPieChart
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/piechart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String drawPieChart(ModelMap model)
    {
        Slice s1 = Slice.newSlice(15, Color.newColor("CACACA"), "Mac", "Mac");
        Slice s2 = Slice.newSlice(50, Color.newColor("DF7417"), "Window","Window");
        Slice s3 = Slice.newSlice(25, Color.newColor("951800"), "Linux","Linux");
        Slice s4 = Slice.newSlice(10, Color.newColor("01A1DB"), "Others","Others");

        PieChart pieChart = GCharts.newPieChart(s1, s2, s3, s4);
        pieChart.setTitle("Google Pie Chart", Color.BLACK, 15);
        pieChart.setSize(720, 360);
        pieChart.setThreeD(true);

        model.addAttribute("pieUrl", pieChart.toURLString());

        return "display";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>SpringMVC 3.2 + Google Chart</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/applnConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>frontController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applnConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.himtech" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/jsps/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>himtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvc_googlechart</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>springmvc_googlechart Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.charts4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>charts4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>springmvc_googlechart</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: the error has nothing to do with java code or xml configuration of the application, can you show us your pom (or part of it) and which command did you use before getting the error? And also, the error details

Comment: @DI Matteo i added pom.xml .could you please help me for this

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the `jetty` plugin prefix is [not recognized by default](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) (as part of default plugins) nor configured in your settings.

Change the `build` section you mentioned as below (that is, add the Jenkins Maven Plugin to it):

```
<build>
    <finalName>springmvc_googlechart</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.8.v20150217</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>7777</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

By defining the Jetty Maven Plugin as part of your POM, Maven will properly recognize the `jetty` prefix/alias from command line, hence executing the following will work:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Note: in the configuration above, Jetty will run on port `7777` (hence, accessible from `http://localhost:7777`), you can change it as required. By default the application will be deployed under the server root (the URL previously mentioned). If you want to access it from `http://localhost:7777/springmvc_googlechart`, you can then add the following to the above `configuration` section:

```
<webApp>
    <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
</webApp>
```

Check the [official plugin documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) for further configuration.